# Random Noise Voltage

Tags: voltage, power, signal, rms, random

I have a signal I am interested in obtaining power from. The best way to describe the signal is that it is random.

[image]

In the graph, the voltage fluctuates from negative to positive with an RMS of 0.5 volts. What circuit would be useful to obtain power from a voltage signal similar to this one?

I am interested in knowing how to obtain power from a signal similar to the signal in the graph. It is random.
The max impedance of the source at 1 kHz is 3.5kOhm. The signal will fluctuate at around 0.5 to 2Hz. Will impedance increase or decrease? The source is a piezoelectric transducer. The max voltage will be from 4 to 12 volts.

Source of image: USC, Doug Button
https://slideplayer.com/slide/6121107/

Comment: What is the source impedance? You might have voltage but that's no use unless the source can supply current. How much power are you hoping to get? Please put all the details into your question.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be a cold blanket, but you're pretty much out of luck for any normal definition of "useful power".

You have a signal which produces ~ 2v pk-pk with a source impedance of 3.5 k. There is a well-known relationship that states/shows that you'll get maximum power into a load when the load impedance is equal to the source impedance. So in this case, the peak power you might expect would be something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fno4Sq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and it should be pretty obvious that the maximum power will be $$P = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{0.5^2}{3500} = 0.07\text{ mW} $$ or 70 microwatts. If you don't get the numbers, the voltage on the load will be 0.5 because the source impedance cuts it in half.

And that's the peak. RMS is one quarter that (since the rms voltage is half the peak), or about 17 microwatts. And any real collection device will have efficiencies less than one.

Are you sure that 10 microwatts or so is worth your time and trouble?

And all of this is before you get into the problems of things like diode drops which will make your life really miserable. So 10 microwatts is actually wildly optimistic.